# Mapped type from array with key change

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say that I have this:

```
export type ParamDecl = ["input" | "output", "float" | "int" | "bool", string][];

const params: ParamDecl = [["input", "float", "x"], ["output", "float", "a"], ["input", "int", "y"], ["output", "bool", "b"]];
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
export type Converted = {
  x: "float",
  a: "float",
  y: "int",
  b: "bool"
};
```

By using generics and mapped types (yes, I am discarding the `"input" | "output"` part; I'll think about that later). I want to be able to do this:

```
let dict: AsDictionary<typeof params>;
```

I tried using the following mapped type:

```
export type AsDictionary<X extends ParamDecl> = { [K in keyof X as X[K][2]]: X[K][1] };
```

But I get 2 errors; I think the second one is a consequence of the first one.

[image: The errors I get.]

```
Type 'X[K][2]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'X[keyof X][2]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'X[string][2] | X[number][2] | X[symbol][2]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
      Type 'X[string][2]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2322)
Type '2' cannot be used to index type 'X[K]'.ts(2536)
```

I think `X[string][2]` should be more or less valid; the only issue if any is that it should be `X[number][2]` if anything, because the input type it's an array.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `keyof X` in the mapped type. `X` is an array which has dozens of other properties like `push` or `pop` or `length`. You can't index those with `2` as they are not tuples/arrays.

You need to map over the union of elements in `X` with `X[number]`.

```
export type AsDictionary<X extends ParamDecl> = { 
    [K in X[number] as K[2]]: K[1] 
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKBDKGC2ARYAYwBs4BeOKYDAEwgDtjE4AKK2hpuAbQCIBLemACuMXnAA%20cXhFEixAGmkAzYhAxjJ0wZqm8ARhAjFeSgM4woggOYBdAJTdbAbgCwAKA%20EGFuGCy4ZuQ8fILypipqGhG8ILy2SnyyMOFKvKrqitIY8YkCQqIxOjGIuTwycoVphsYx%20vG2cBhB3vQWbp7uAPRdcKCQsAjIqADCDABuwLDANMEA3h49cMsgAFyRmaaLvcsY6%20lRitvLcIj7xQrHy-r7NSbHAL4dHv3Q8EgocACCZnj8hDB%20AwsIgADwADT6IBgwHoNCCmGw%20CIxAAfPM4B4TjwANJwQRwcHcejCHD6KaNZpwHHcABMtls6xpAEZGh4nh4PB9RhMpjDZhQfn8AUD6CDQdyIMo-AEcGZUUA)

Comment: Thank you! I probably should point out another mistake that I made in my original code, and that your snippet fixes. If one intends to do `AsDictionary<typeof params>` then they should not type `params` as `const params: ParamDecl` because it's going to hide the real type from `AsDictionary` and things are not going to work as intended.